# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(7-i, -3+i\sqrt{8}, 4-i\sqrt{10})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(7-i, -3+i\sqrt{8}, 4-i\sqrt{10})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$.

How do I go about beginning to prove this?

Comment: Double inclusion, man. You can show that generators of the first field belong to the second one, and viceversa.

Comment: @Crostul - I have one inclusion: I was able to show pretty easily that $\mathbb{Q}(7-i, -3+i\sqrt{8}, 4-i\sqrt{10}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$. However, the other inclusion is eluding me.

Comment: For the other inclusion, having $7-i$, you get $i$. Having $\sqrt{8}= 2 \sqrt{2}$, you get $\sqrt{2}$. Having $\sqrt{10}$, divide by $\sqrt{2}$ to get $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was making it much more complicated - by trying to write all of the elements and get $i, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}$ from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\alpha=7-\mathrm i$. Then $\mathrm i=7-\alpha$.

Similarly, if $\beta=-3+\mathrm i\sqrt 8=-3+2\,\mathrm i\sqrt 2$,
$$\sqrt2=\frac{\beta+3}{2\,\mathrm i}=\frac{\beta+3}{2(7-\alpha)}.$$
&c.